# Jenkins/Groovy- Job DSL plugin - git() vs git{}

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

As per [Job DSL plugin API documentation for Git](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.ScmContext.git), there are two forms to use it:

1. git('repo_url')
2. git {...}  //with lot of additional options

What is the difference between these two approaches ? 
One is a method call and the other one is calling a closure ? 
As per [this article](https://www.happycoders.eu/devops/jenkins-tutorial-create-jobs-with-job-dsl/), I guess both forms are calling a Groovy closure + some Groovy syntactic sugar.

Comment: After some more research, my current understanding - all below 3 forms are calling method git(String url, Closure configure = null)
1.git() - no closure passed as parameter to method
2.git(){} - Groovy syntactic sugar  - If the last parameter of a method call is a closure, it can be passed outside the parentheses
3.git {} - another Groovy syntactic sugar - Groovy allows omitting parenthesis for method calls - for example println("Hello") and println "Hello" are  same in Groovy. In this case, the only parameter is a closure.
Could some one please validate that my understanding is correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One is a method call and the other one is calling a closure ?

Both are method calls - but the first takes a string on `git` - while the latter takes a closure as argument.

As per the api-doc api you shared above, it looks like the first one - `git {}` - provides maximum options to setup the SCM context - that includes an option to manipulate directly the generated XML through `configure` closure. All the others seem to be the variants of this option with the last argument as the `configure` closure.

> If the last parameter of a method call is a closure, it can be passed outside the parentheses

Yes, you are right. And, if the closure is the only method argument, then method can be called with just that and without any parentheses. That's exactly what the first call is about `git {}`